# Integration changing limits - does the question have an error?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am asking about changing the limits of integration.

I have the following integral to evaluate -

$$\int_2^{3}\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$ using the substitution $x = sec \theta$.

The problem states

**Use the substitution to change the limits into the form $\int_a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $\pi$.**

Now, this is what I did.

$$ x= \sec \theta$$
$$\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \sec\theta \tan\theta$$
$$dx = sec\theta tan\theta \ d\theta$$

$$\begin{align}\int_2^{3}\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx \\
&= \int\frac{1}{(\sec^2\theta-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sec\theta \tan\theta \,d\theta \\
&= \int\frac{\sec\theta \tan\theta}{(\tan^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \,d\theta \\
&= \int\frac{\sec\theta \tan\theta}{\tan^3\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \int\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \int \csc\theta \cot\theta \, d\theta
\end{align}$$

But here is my problem. 
I know that when $x = 2$, 
$$2 = \sec \theta$$
$$\frac{1}{2} = \cos \theta$$
$$\frac{\pi}{3} = \theta$$

but when $x = 3$
$$3 = \sec \theta$$
$$\frac{1}{3} = \cos \theta$$
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = \theta = $$
but this does not give me a definite result in $\pi$. 
The book says the following -

[image]

where $\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}$
Am I the only one or is the book wrong in this instance?

Comment: Fist things first, your substitution should be $x=\sec \theta$, since $x=\sec x$ is an equation.

Comment: @JaideepKhare typo, fixed!

Comment: I have edited further. Looks good now.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I had already made these edits, and actually, I had aligned them using the `\align` environment and applied `\left` `\right` as well.

Comment: the result should be $$2/3\,\sqrt {3}-3/4\,\sqrt {2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how did you manage that?! Can you answer the question please because I am confused! It is correct by the way!

Comment: with software.!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Sorry for that, your edit was applied while I was middle editing, but you didn't correct $x$ and $\theta$, that's why I am not rolling back to your edit. Because this version, though doesn't look great, but is correct. You're welcome to edit further in this version and beautify.

Comment: If the book were right, the integral would be equal to 0. (as both limits are equal) You are right in that $\arccos\left(\frac 1 3\right)$ is not a multiple of pi, so I would suggest an error in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is indeed incorrect.

$$arccos(\frac{1}{3}) \neq \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Note if it was the case that $arccos(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$ as stated in the solutions,

then the integral would total 0.

Comment: Now finish the solution!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, write $a=\arccos\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\arccos\frac{1}{3}$. One can take care of them at the end.

It is true that $a=\pi/3$, but it's definitely wrong that $b=\pi/3$. Actually, $b\approx1.230959$, but you won't need that.

The integral becomes
$$
\int_a^b-\frac{1}{(\sec^2\theta-1)^{3/2}}\sec^2\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta
$$
Now it's better to write the integrand in terms of sine and cosine, recalling that the interval of integration is contained in $(0,\pi/2)$. Thus
$$
\sec^2\theta-1=
\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}=
\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}
$$
so the integrand is
$$
-\frac{\cos^3\theta}{\sin^3\theta}\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\sin\theta=
-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}
$$
Thus we get
$$
\int_2^{3}\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx=
\int_a^b-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta=
\int_a^b-\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\,d(\sin\theta)=
\left[\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\right]_a^b
$$
Since $a=\arccos(1/2)$ and $b=\arccos(1/3)$, we get
$$
\sin a=\sqrt{1-\cos^2a}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\qquad
\sin b=\sqrt{1-\cos^2b}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}
$$
with no “sign uncertainty”, because $a$ and $b$ lie in $(0,\pi/2)$.

Thus the integral is
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$